# Hex to char conversion and dumping output

Tags: c, casting, char, hex

I am trying to assign the first 8bytes of a character buffer with "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0". I am able to verify the buffer is constructed right. Whenever i try to hexdump using my utility, i get unexpected output. Not sure, if i am missing something else here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

static void hexdump(const char *src, int count)
{
    int i;  

    if (count == 0)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

        printf("%02x ", src[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }   
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
   char msg_buff[148];
   memset(msg_buff, 0, 148);
   int a[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0};
   sprintf(msg_buff, "%02x %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", a[0], a[1], 
 a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);
   printf("packet %s \n", msg_buff); // 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0
   hexdump(msg_buff, 148);
}
```

**My output**

```
packet 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 
30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 30 20 30 
30 20 30 30 20 41 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

**Expected output**

```
packet 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00
```

Comment: `char` --> `unsigned char` then  `unsigned char msg_buff[148];
memset(msg_buff, 0, sizeof msg_buff);
unsigned char a[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0};
memcpy(msg_buff, a, sizeof a);
hexdump(msg_buff, sizeof msg_buff);`, `"%02x "` --> `"%02X "`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: you really like to fit all your answers inside the comment box. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to delete `a[8]` from the following function in your code, because the length of `a[]` is 8, however your code has 9 members:

`sprintf(msg_buff, "%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);`

Secondly, you need to change your defined variables type, your code should look like the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

static void hexdump(const char *src, int count)
{
    int i;

    if (count == 0)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

        printf("%02x ", src[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 16 == 0)
            printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    unsigned char  msg_buff[148];
    memset(msg_buff, 0, 148);
    unsigned char  a[8] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0 };
    sprintf(msg_buff, "%02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]);
    printf("packet %s \n", msg_buff); // 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A0
    hexdump(msg_buff, 148);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`hexdump(msg_buff, 148);`

to 
`hexdump(a, 8);`

In your code you are dumping the string

Comment: I need to have hex values in the message buffer with valid values.

Comment: what does it mean?, you have there exactly what you put there